# Syntax error on colon in ansible command argument

Tags: json, command, ansible

I'm developing a playbook to maintain a Kubernetes cluster. There is a command I have to execute to add an entry in etcd:

```
- command: etcdctl mk /kube-centos/network/config "{ \"Network\": \"172.30.0.0/16\", \"SubnetLen\": 24, \"Backend\": { \"Type\": \"vxlan\" } }"
```

When trying to execute, Ansible gives a syntax error on the first colon:

```
- command: etcdctl mk /kube-centos/network/config '{ "Network": "172.30.0.0/16", "SubnetLen": 24, "Backend": { "Type": "vxlan" } }'
                                                              ^ here
```

I can't figure out how to escape these characters. What is the best way to pass a JSON argument to a command like this?

---

There are actually two ways to fix this:

**Answer 1**

Surround the entire command in single quotes:

```
- command: 'etcdctl mk /kube-centos/network/config "{ \"Network\": \"172.30.0.0/16\", \"SubnetLen\": 24, \"Backend\": { \"Type\": \"vxlan\" } }"'
```

**Answer 2 (Preferred)**

Surround all colons in double quotes:

```
- command: etcdctl mk /kube-centos/network/config "{ \"Network\"":" \"172.30.0.0/16\", \"SubnetLen\"":" 24, \"Backend\"":" { \"Type\"":" \"vxlan\" } }"
```

Comment: Just enclose it in double quotes. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to enclose the colon in double quotes. Works always.

```
- command: etcdctl mk /kube-centos/network/config "{ \"Network\"":" \"172.30.0.0/16\", \"SubnetLen\"":" 24, \"Backend\"":" { \"Type\"":" \"vxlan\" } }"
```

Comment: Is that the preferred way to do this? Apparently, there are two ways to solve the problem

Comment: It is preferred. If you decide to enclose your command in single quotes and if you have single quotes in your command body, you'll end up escaping that single quote. Choose whatever works for you.

Comment: I thought about it and like your solution better. I'll change the accepted answer to yours, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/2769)

you need to quote the whole thing like this:

```
- command: 'echo "semicolon is: bad"'
```

cause ansible does not like semicolons much.